# How do I change attr() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my current format

```
<div class="post-item" id="4126">
  ...entry...
</div>
```

With this id format will return to

`Error: value of attribute "id" invalid: "4" cannot start a name`

Now I want to change the id will be `id="post_4126"`

And the question, how do I replace current jQuery will be working with the `id="post_4126"`

```
url: "more.php?lastid=" + $(".post-item:last").attr("id")
```

Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url: "more.php?lastid=" + $(".post-item:last").attr("id").split('_')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question correctly, i think you want to change attr from `#4126` to `#post_4126` since id's cannot be pure numbers.  This is how to do it:

```
var x = $(".post-item:last").attr("id");
url: "more.php?lastid=" + 'post_' + x;
```